# what is the outofsource error from cmake

Tags: cmake, mingw, tpm

I am trying to compile something with cmake and it gives an error about requiring out of source. How can I find out more about this error please? 
Here is the output

```
C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\tpm_emulator-0.7.4\tpm_emulator-0.7.4\build>cmake ../
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (message):
  TPM_Emulator requires an out of source build.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/sansari/Downloads/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Here is the content of CMakeLists.txt

```
# Software-based Trusted Platform Module (TPM) Emulator
# Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Mario Strasser <mast@gmx.net>
#
# $Id: CMakeLists.txt 475 2011-12-20 18:21:19Z mast $

project(TPM_Emulator C)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)
set(CMAKE_ALLOW_LOOSE_LOOP_CONSTRUCTS true)
if(COMMAND cmake_policy)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0003 NEW)
endif()

# enforce out of source build
string(COMPARE EQUAL "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" IS_INSOURCE)
if(IS_INSOURCE)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "${PROJECT_NAME} requires an out of source build.")
endif()

# set project and build version
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MINOR 7)
string(REGEX REPLACE ".*Revision: ([0-9]+).*" "\\1" ${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_BUILD "$Revision: 475 $")

# create project configuration
if(WIN32)
STRING(REGEX REPLACE "\\\\" "/" PROGRAMFILES "$ENV{PROGRAMFILES}/${PROJECT_NAME}")
set(TPM_LOG_FILE "${PROGRAMFILES}/tpmd.log")
set(TPM_STORAGE_NAME "${PROGRAMFILES}/tpm_emulator-1_2_${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MAJOR}_${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MINOR}
")
set(TPM_DEVICE_NAME "//./pipe/tpmd:0")
elseif(APPLE)
set(TPM_LOG_FILE "/private/var/log/tpmd.log")
set(TPM_SOCKET_NAME "/private/var/run/tpm/tpmd_socket:0")
set(TPM_STORAGE_NAME "/private/var/lib/tpm/tpm_emulator-1_2_${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MAJOR}_${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(TPM_DEVICE_NAME "/dev/tpm")
else()
set(TPM_LOG_FILE "/var/log/tpmd.log")
set(TPM_SOCKET_NAME "/var/run/tpm/tpmd_socket:0")
set(TPM_STORAGE_NAME "/var/lib/tpm/tpm_emulator-1_2_${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MAJOR}_${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MINOR}")
set(TPM_DEVICE_NAME "/dev/tpm")
endif()
configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h)
add_definitions(-Wall -Werror -Wno-unused-parameter -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Wwrite-strings)
if("${CMAKE_SYSTEM}" MATCHES "Linux")
    add_definitions(-Wextra)
endif()
if(USE_OPENSSL)
    add_definitions(-DUSE_OPENSSL)
endif()
include_directories("/opt/local/include")
link_directories("/opt/local/lib")

# configure CPack
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR ${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MAJOR})
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR ${${PROJECT_NAME}_VERSION_MINOR})
set(CPACK_SOURCE_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "tpm_emulator-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.4")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_GENERATOR "TGZ")
set(CPACK_SOURCE_IGNORE_FILES ".svn/" "/build/" "/.project" "/.cproject")
set(CPACK_GENERATOR "ZIP")
set(CPACK_SET_DESTDIR ON)
include(CPack)

# include root directories
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

# add internal libraries
add_subdirectory(tpm)
add_subdirectory(mtm)
add_subdirectory(crypto)

# add TDDL
add_subdirectory(tddl)

# add kernel modules
add_subdirectory(tpmd_dev)

# add executables
add_subdirectory(tpmd)
```

@ Dan Shepler - Thanks. I deleted the source and unpacked it again. Now I get a different message as follows:

```
$ cmake ../
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
  The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:

    cl

  is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.

  To use the NMake generator with Visual C++, cmake must be run from a shell
  that can use the compiler cl from the command line.  This environment is
  unable to invoke the cl compiler.  To fix this problem, run cmake from the
  Visual Studio Command Prompt (vcvarsall.bat).

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
  the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/sansari/Downloads/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/sansari/Downloads/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Given that I have installed MinGw. I believe I have to set my compiler as gcc. And I believe this would be my path

C:\MinGW\bin
```

I just did these two commands to set environment variables to the path of the compiler I know, but I still get the error. I saw gcc.exe in the C:\MinGw\bin. I am gonna try adding the name of the gcc.exe to the environment variable path.

```
set CC=C:\MinGW\bin



set CMAKE_C_COMPILER=C:\MinGW\bin
```

---

I found the variable that I need to change in the build directory and changed it. Now it says

```
$ cmake ../
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_5e307\fast"
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/sansari/Downloads/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"nmake" "/NOLOGO" "cmTC_5e307\fast"



  Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "nmake" "/NOLOGO"
  "cmTC_5e307\fast"





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/sansari/Downloads/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/sansari/Downloads/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

---

I found [this](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=9286) link and checked my path variable on Windows 10. I actually had to add a user path; I just had system path. I put MInGw\bin, msys\bin, and msys\local\bin, and cmake in my path.

I think it worked this time. What I did I used the cmd running in Admin mode rather than MinGw shell. Here is the output ...

```
C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\tpm_emulator-0.7.4\tpm_emulator-0.7.4\build>cmake ../
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.3
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/sansari/Downloads/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/tpm_emulator-0.7.4/build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is explicitly output by this line:

```
    message(FATAL_ERROR "${PROJECT_NAME} requires an out of source build.")
```

Normally, I wouldn't expect the if condition to be triggered based on the `cmake` command you gave.  I would first check to see if there are some CMake artifacts left over in the source directory `C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\tpm_emulator-0.7.4\tpm_emulator-0.7.4` from a previous configuration attempt, which could cause CMake to refuse to use your build directory.  If so, then remove CMakeCache.txt, CMakeFiles/ etc. from the source directory (or just remove the whole source directory and unpack it again).  Otherwise, to debug what's happening I would insert something like this temporarily just above the `if(IS_INSOURCE)` statement:

```
message(STATUS "CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
message(STATUS "CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
message(STATUS "IS_INSOURCE = ${IS_INSOURCE}")
```